# How to save function argument names after it is wrapped?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a wrapped function. I want this function to contain its original name and argument names. I am using Python 2.7.

This is not my original code, but represents my question:

```
from functools import wraps

def deco(func):
    @wraps(func) #here i tried @wraps(func, assigned=("__name__", "__code__")) but it seems the __code__ attribute is read only
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@deco
def f(a):
    pass

print f.__code__.co_varnames
```

Return:

```
('args', 'kwargs')
```

Expect:

```
('a',)
```

I find the function attribute `__closure__` which helps to get the original function and thus the original arguments. But if I need the argument names in the decorator and the function has multiple wrappers, I have to write a new function that returns the original argument names of the wrapped function.

It's not hard, but if the functools method `wraps` can assign attribute `__name__`, maybe there is another method that assigns arguments?

Comment: *"I'm using Python 2.7"* **why?**

Comment: If you're really stuck on Python 2 with no hope of upgrade, you could try to use an old Python 2-compatible version of the [`decorator` library](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/). Why are you using Python 2, though? The right way forward will depend on if the answer to that question is "because I just don't want to upgrade", "because that's the version on the long-term support OS we're running", "because that's the version embedded in the tool I need to work with", "because I'm stuck on Jython and Jython still doesn't support Python 3", or something else.

Comment: I'm writing a script for a program that only supports python 2.7!

Comment: `functools,wraps` (at least in Python 3) includes the line `wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped`. This suggests that if `f` is the name of the decorated function then `f.__wrapped__.__code__.co_varnames` will have the info that you want.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Unfortunately, `__wrapped__` is a Python 3 addition.

Comment: You could write your own version of `wraps` that includes that line. The source for `wraps` is easy to understand and not terribly long, and you could probably shorten it for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks John Coleman, I added the `if '__wrapped__' not in wrapper.__dict__: wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped` in the `update_wrapper` function. But I don't know when I can use the `__wrapped__` attribute in the decorator because I don't know what order the decorators will have. I need to check if the function has the `__wrapped__` attribute. It looks like the `__closure__` attribute should be used though.

Comment: @okdog: It is not possible for nested decorators to execute in an order where one decorator tries to access `__wrapped__` on a wrapper before another decorator sets the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in method to set the wrapped function arguments to the wrapper function. So I created a new decorator that creates a `__wrapped__` attribute for the original function. This attribute contains a self-function, so you don't need to check for its existence in the first decorator. The wrapper is then updated with `__dict__` and `__name__` from the original function.

```
from inspect import getargspec


def wrap_wrapper(wrapped):
    def update_wrapper_attributes(wrapper):
        if '__wrapped__' not in wrapped.__dict__:  # it will only work in the first decorator and not let overwrite
            # __wrapped__ with next wrapper function
            wrapped.__wrapped__ = wrapped  # I don't need to check if there is an attribute __wrapped__
        wrapper.__dict__.update(wrapped.__dict__)  # now wrapper have an attribute __wrapped__
        wrapper.__name__ = wrapped.__name__  # save the original function name through decorators
        return wrapper
    return update_wrapper_attributes


def another_deco(func):
    @wrap_wrapper(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kvargs):
        print "FROM THE SECOND DECORATOR ORIGINAL FUNCTION ARG NAMES:", getargspec(func.__wrapped__)[0]
        return func(*args, **kvargs)
    return wrap


def deco_who_takes_parameters(a, b):
    def deco(func):
        @wrap_wrapper(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kvargs):
            print "FROM THE FIRST DECORATOR ORIGINAL FUNCTION ARG NAMES:", getargspec(func.__wrapped__)[0]
            a(b)  # do something with a and b
            return func(*args, **kvargs)
        return wrap
    return deco


@another_deco
@deco_who_takes_parameters(str, 1)
def f(a):
    return a


f(1)

print "FINALLY:", getargspec(f.__wrapped__)[0]
print "WRAPPED FUNCTION NAME IS THE SAME AS ORIGINAL FUNCTION NAME:", f.__name__
```

Result:

```
FROM THE SECOND DECORATOR ORIGINAL FUNCTION ARG NAMES: ['a']
FROM THE FIRST DECORATOR ORIGINAL FUNCTION ARG NAMES: ['a']
FINALLY: ['a']
WRAPPED FUNCTION NAME IS THE SAME AS ORIGINAL FUNCTION NAME: f
```

Comment: That is very, very fragile - it assumes that the only closures your code encounters will be decorator-generated wrappers, and that the wrapped function will always be the last closure variable. If you only need this to be compatible with decorators you write, it'd be better to just save a `__wrapped__` attribute. If you need this to be compatible with other decorators, you're going to have issues.

Comment: Also, `co_varnames` includes things that aren't arguments. [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, the `original_args_names` will encounter wrappers generated by decorators, and it seems that the last variable of `__closure__` is always a wrapper function. With the `__wrapped__` attribute, I need to check if the function has the `__wrapped__` attribute, because the function is not wrapped in the first decorator and I don't know the order of the decorators.

Comment: "With the `__wrapped__` attribute, I need to check if the function has the `__wrapped__` attribute" - yeah, but you can just... check that. It's simple, and more reliable than making assumptions about `__closure__`. If you ever call your `original_args_names` function on [a closure that has nothing to do with decorators](https://ideone.com/Vswldo), or a [decorator that uses other closure variables](https://ideone.com/5GbIAC), you can end up mistaking the wrong object for the function you need to inspect.

Comment: @user2357112: You're right. It is better to create a wrapper attribute that contains the original function. I just edit my answer!